# What should I choose a database. I hate to relational databases

Tags: database

What should I choose a database, I hate to relational databases, are there any advanced database
My request is to simple, easy, and powerful

no mysql,no ms server,no sqlite,no orancle,

thanks

Comment: A bit more information would be helpful

Comment: This question is very unclear....

Comment: Why do you hate relational databases? telling us more information allows us to better answer your request.

Comment: Microsoft made one a while ago called:  Excel.

Answer (score 3):

this seems like a silly question... "I need to use a database, but I refuse to use a database..." use one or don't.

not really sure why you hate databases.. then are really simple, stable, and work with every language.

You could go for something like hadoop and hive/pig, but that is WAY more then you are looking for and far more complicated the mysql.

You need to give more info as to: 
1) what you are trying to do
2) the data set sizes involved
3) the usage patterns that this will be hit with

Answer (score 3):

Wow... way to win friends and influence people right there in the question title.

Take a look at NoSQL.  From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL:

> NoSQL is a database movement which began in early to mid 2009. The term refers to non-relational data stores that do not need a fixed schema, and that usually avoid join operations.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I understand your question, so I'm not sure if this is the correct answer...

Have you looked at

- [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org) - MongoDB (from "humongous") is a scalable, high-performance, open source, schema-free, document-oriented database. MongoDB bridges the gap between key-value stores (which are fast and highly scalable) and traditional RDBMS systems (which provide structured schemas and powerful queries).
- [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org) - Apache CouchDB is a document-oriented database that can be queried and indexed in a MapReduce fashion using JavaScript. CouchDB also offers incremental replication with bi-directional conflict detection and resolution.

Simple, Easy, and Powerful - pick any two of the three..